# Upgrading jdk from 8u221 to 8u241 getting java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) exception

Tags: java, java-8

After upgrading JDK8 from 8u221 to 8u241(Minor version change) getting below exception. Please tell me where it went wrong but it is working in 8u231. Please guide me

```
WARNING: Unable to synchronize with remote stored reports. Some stored report might not be available.
    com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.ReportSchedulerNotAvailableException: Unable to connect to the Task-Scheduler with URL 'https://localhost:48443/'!
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.TaskReportScheduler.updateTaskSchedulerModule(TaskReportScheduler.java:300)
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.TaskReportScheduler.setTaskSchedulerConnection(TaskReportScheduler.java:170)
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.ReportSchedulerUtils.getReportSchedulerIfAvailable(ReportSchedulerUtils.java:130)
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.ReportSchedulerUtils.isSchedulerServerDisabled(ReportSchedulerUtils.java:268)
        at com.watch4net.apg.v2.gui.stats.FrontendStats.initialize(FrontendStats.java:156)
        at com.watch4net.apg.v2.gui.stats.FrontendStats$ApplicationListener.onStartup(FrontendStats.java:116)
        at com.watch4net.apg.common.util.ApplicationListenerUtils.startup(ApplicationListenerUtils.java:54)
        at com.watch4net.apg.v2.gui.servlet.listener.ApgListener.contextInitialized(ApgListener.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.ReportSchedulerNotAvailableException: Unable to retrieve the 'task-scheduler' module!
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.WebserviceCommunicator.getTaskSchedulerModule(WebserviceCommunicator.java:82)
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.TaskReportScheduler.updateTaskSchedulerModule(TaskReportScheduler.java:296)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:208)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getModules(Unknown Source)
        at com.watch4net.apg.report.scheduling.gui.WebserviceCommunicator.getTaskSchedulerModule(WebserviceCommunicator.java:70)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
        at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:879)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:720)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:1144)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1281)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1191)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:369)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at`enter code here` sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:104)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the only thing you've changed is the JDK? In most cases "Broken pipe" means that the client unexpectedly closed the connection which is only detected when the server tries to write to the stream - so I'd check whether and why the client is doing that.

Comment: Ya Thomas I have checked it is failing for only 8u241 and working with 8u221 &  8u231.is this Java security issue?

Comment: @Thomas - a broken pipe during SSL negotiation typically means that one end has decided that it can't negotiate a satisfactory set of parameters with the other end.

Comment: Add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to the JVM parameters and look at the information that is logged.

Comment: @stephen if it is known issue please provide me the steps to resolve it. I tried in all possible ways to resolve it but no luck. I think it is Java security issue related to cacerts. Please help me

Comment: Did you do what I suggested?  There were a number of security related changes in 8u241 according to the release notes.  But the information you have provided does not allow us to tie your problem to a specific change ... or hint at a fix.   But if you follow my previous advice, there may be more clues.

Comment: Release notes: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u241-relnotes-5813177.html  bug fixes: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u241-bugfixes-5813332.html

Comment: Since the connection is disconnected during an SSL/TLS handshake, and since as Stephen C pointed out, TLS security has been tightened in Java 8 update 241, I am inclined to believe the two are related.  I would first try to determine whether the URL that’s being accessed is returning a certificate whose common name exactly matches the host name in the URL itself.